# HTML PHP check box

Tags: php, html, css

How can I style my code so that the check box can be aligned beside the table.

All of the check boxes are appearing above the table, but not beside it.

Consider the following snippet of code as well as the picture attached at the end.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Furni checker </title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <h1>Furniture Lookup / Furniture Checker</h1> <br />
    <br /><p>This tool is used for removal or check furniture on a user account.</p> <br />
    <h2> Instructions : </h2> <br />
    <p> Lookup User ID and Lookup for the Furniture! </p>

    <?php
      require_once "global.php";

      echo '<h1>Furniture Lookup / Furniture Checker</h1>
      <br /><p>This tool is used for removal or check furniture on a user account.</p>';

      echo '<br />
      <form method="post">
      Username:
      <input type="text" name="user">
      <input type="submit" value="Lookup">
      </form>';

      if (isset($_POST['user'])) {
        $user = filter($_POST['user']);
        $getUser = dbquery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.username = '" . $user . "' ");

        while($show1 = mysql_fetch_array($getUser)) {
          echo ''. $show1['id']. '';        
        }
      }
    ?>

    <br />

    <?php
      echo '
      <form method="post">
      ID:
      <input type="text" name="id">
      <input type="submit" value="Lookup">
      </form>';

      if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
        $id = filter($_POST['id']);
        $getFurniture = dbquery("SELECT public_name FROM furniture JOIN items ON items.base_item = furniture.id WHERE items.user_id = '" . $id . "' ORDER BY public_name ASC ");

        echo '<table border=1 cellpadding=1 width="10%">';

        while($show = mysql_fetch_array($getFurniture)) {
          //echo  ''. $show['public_name'].'' ;
          echo '<tr class="t_row">';
          echo '<input type="checkbox"> <td>' .$show['public_name']. '</td>';
          echo '</tr>';

        }

        echo '</input>';
        echo '</table>';    
      }
    ?>
```

**Image:**

[image: checkbox_image]

Comment: You should add `<td>` before checkbox like this `echo '<td>' .$show['public_name']. '<input type="checkbox"></td>';`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
          <?php


              if (isset($_POST['submit']))
              {
                      $id = filter($_POST['id']);
                      $getFurniture = dbquery("SELECT public_name FROM furniture JOIN items ON items.base_item = furniture.id WHERE items.user_id = '" . $id . "' ORDER BY public_name ASC ");

                      echo '<table border=1 cellpadding=1 width="10%">';

                      while($show = mysql_fetch_array($getFurniture)){
                      //echo  ''. $show['public_name'].'' ;
                       echo '<tr class="t_row">';
                       echo '<td>' .$show['public_name']. '</td><td><input type="checkbox" /> </td>';
                       echo '</tr>';

                      }

                  echo '</table>';

              }

          ?>
```

Let me know if it's not working.